# Iterating through a column(string) with a while loop and concatenating 0s

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I made the following script/query in TSQL(to which I happen to be a begginer):

```
USE HIS_WEB
GO
DECLARE @NSS_LENGTH AS INT, @NSS AS VARCHAR(30)
SET @NSS_LENGTH = LEN((SELECT Folio FROM DBO.Pacientes WHERE IdPaciente=1003))
SET @NSS = (SELECT Folio FROM DBO.Pacientes WHERE IdPaciente=1003)
WHILE (@NSS_LENGTH < 18)
BEGIN
    SET @NSS = @NSS + '0' 
    SET @NSS_LENGTH = @NSS_LENGTH + 1
    --PRINT @NSS
END
SELECT @NSS AS NSS_AUTOFILL

SELECT Folio,* FROM DBO.Pacientes WHERE IdPaciente=1003
```

This is what I get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUq16.png)

It does what is suppossed to but it has a mayor flaw. The `while` loop iterates through a single value. What I want is that it iterates through a column of string values and it concatenates 0s until the while loop becomes false.

Like this one:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRtio.png)

The `@NSS` variable can only store a single value. I think this is where the main issue lies. Can I store multiple values in a variable?. For the record, I tried that and got the followeing error 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'.

I don't know if this is of any help but I addressed the very same task with `PYTHON` and succeded.

```
NSS = ['9413880090','97845687','94138800901M1988','5218']
for i in NSS:
    x = len(i)
    while x < 18:
        i += '0'
        x += 1
    print(i)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZzvQ.png)

I want my TSQL code to behave similarly to my python script. Is that possible or I need to tackle this problem in a different fashion(cursors)?.

Note: I don't want to use `UPDATE` statements to update my string values. I just want to get the concatenation done in the resultset.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I want my TSQL code to behave similarly to my python script"  Why???  SQL is a set based language.  Why do you loop SQL???  If you want to loop use Python.

Comment: Hense the words 'behave similarly' but I get your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  nss_autofill = left(Folio + replicate('0', 18), 18),
        -- rest of your columns here...
from    dbo.Pacientes
```

The [`replicate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function does what it says on the tin. Given some `varchar` value as argument 1, and an `int` as argument 2, it creates a new `varchar` value which is arg1 repeated arg2 times.

[`Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) then takes a varchar as the first argument, and returns the first N characters, where N is the second argument.

Comment: I shall give this a try. Thanks for the input.